# How to enable user based security in Jetty for non user interactive web service

Tags: java, security, curl, jetty

I have a background http client which sends http requests to my server which has SSL based authorisation and service is deployed on jetty. I want to add user based authentication.

My client is background process so user name , password and role will be sent in http request , can it be set in HTTP header and my servlet can match the user name , password and role without any user intervention ?

My client is using curl library in C++ and server is in Java.